# With PSA Standard Platform user license, the user is not able to edit assignments from resource planner. He has the permission sets as users who can

Tags: permission-sets, financialforce

PSA Standard Platform user license, the user is not able to edit assignments from resource planner. He has the permission sets as users who can edit. The user setup and managed packages is the same as well

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In PSA Resource planner, this user is not able to edit assignments. All assignments are greyed out and get 'you don't have permission to edit'